# Controlled Intervention Before/After

Tags: case-control-study, controlling-for-a-variable

I have an intervention that I'd like to determine the effect of (before/after). All of the data has been divided into a treatment or control group.

The issue is that the treatment/intervention took place at varying times across the treatment group, over the course of multiple years. Likewise, the treatment itself could take > 1 year to take effect.

In the meantime, the underlying data is being changed by other (unrelated) factors because the length of time elapsed is so large.

It should be straightforward to determine the before/after effect of the treatment group (comparing a year of 'before' data with a year of 'after' data, not counting the time during intervention installation).

However, it's hard to create a counterfactual. My first thought is randomly assigning pseudo-intervention start/end dates, based on the distributions found in the true intervention data for the treatment group, to the control group and performing a before/after on the control group. That way, I'll be able to tell--regardless of underlying changes b/c of time--the true impact of the intervention. Any thoughts?